# Selenium + Python. Screenshot of an element is smaller than the element

Tags: python, selenium

When I do the `screenshot` of an element using `element.screenshot('filepath')` I do have the `screenshot` cut just like it doesn't fit to the `screenspace`, just like I need to scroll down, but the element is actually is too huge to be entirely in the screen, so how can I get a full screenshot of the element?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `request module.`

```
import requests

path = 'target.jpg'
response = requests.get("URL here", stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as file:
        for pic in response:
            file.write(pic)
```